# Change href attribute in jquery with php

Tags: php, jquery, themes, gentelella

```
$('.buttonFinish').addClass('btn btn-default');
```

Jquery code for the submit looks like this:

```
finish  : $('<a>'+options.labelFinish+'</a>').attr("href","#").addClass("buttonFinish")
```

I need to replace "#" in href with a variable that I can send thru my PHP code.

I tried to do this:

```
 finish  : $('<a>'+options.labelFinish+'</a>').attr("href","<?php echo $someVariable;?>").addClass("buttonFinish")
```

where $someVariable is defined in the PHP code where the form submission link will point to

Comment: Your >?php  should be <?php

Comment: That was a typo just rectified the initial query, still the same problem, my link comes up as /localhost/<?php echo $someVariable;?>

Comment: Please provide all the relevant script. Not at all clear how you are using this. Also the syntax `finish:` seems strange. See [mcve]

Comment: what happens if you remove the quotes?

Comment: By removing the comments I think I break the code or something as the buttons disappear and the form wizard goes bad, i.e. it shows all the steps in a single page with no javascript running

Comment: I try on selecting anchor tag with an ID or specific class.

Comment: Hi Abhijit, I am new to JS can you please tell how to do this with example

Answer (score 1):

You **can** define a variable in php and call it in JS. For example...

**PHP**

```
$someVariable = <?php echo $something ?>
```

**JS**

```
finish  : $('<a>'+options.labelFinish+'</a>').attr("href", $someVariable).addClass("buttonFinish")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, the problem is this is breaking the code. 
This is what the link should look like  http://www.mankomal.com/school/form_wizards.html and this is what it looks like after this http://www.mankomal.com/school/addstudent_tpl.html

Answer (score 0):

```
var someVariable = "<?php echo $something ?>";

finish  : $('<a>'+options.labelFinish+'</a>').attr("href", someVariable).addClass("buttonFinish")
```

Comment: Your answer is very similar to the other existing answer. Please clarify the context. Readers might confuse where to put which line, ie a file interpreted by PHP. I suggest adding an example file name and a wrapping <script> tag.